# Designed in an insidious, manipulative way

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an adjective that is like "bespoke" in that it means purposefully designed (custom-made), but has more negative connotations; it is something cleverly designed to be tricksy, manipulative, controlling etc.

The adjective would likely describe obtuse contracts really well

> Mr Salamander used _______ contracts to bind his unwitting tenants to unfortunate fates

Or maybe to describe a dystopian political body censoring works

> The party's _______ guidelines pretty much eliminated all freedom of expression

I am thinking of words like "insidious", but that doesn't fit because it doesn't have any "intentionally-designed towards a purpose" meaning.

Comment: Poison pen contracts and guidelines, perhaps?

Comment: Not an adjective nor applicable here, but just as a point of interest, a related term in the field of user interfaces is “dark pattern” - “uncheck this box if you don’t want our newsletter” and such.

Answer (score -1):

The two lines call for different words. Here are a few:

- censorious
- convoluted
- deceptive
- diabilical
- draconian
- insidious
- misleading

End those sentences with periods!

Comment: None of these have the meaning of "purposefully designed", "bespoke", "custom-crafted"